# Facebook Share Button - 'Attachment Could Not be Found'

Tags: facebook, button, share, facebook-sharer

I have implemented the Facebook share button as follows:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/bookf1" data-layout="button_count" data-share="false" data-width="180" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button"></div>
```

It appears on my website as expected and clicking it brings up the sharer.php with the expected display. However, when I click the 'Share Link' button it shows the 'thinking' animation for a second then nothing happens. The sharer.php pop-up just remains on-screen.

If I try and share the link via a private message I get an error saying "The Attachment Could Not Be Found".

This is running on a publicly accessible URL.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find this issue anywhere else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similair issue with exactly the same symptoms and wasted some time here.

After clicking my share-button the expected popup opened. In the url it was visible that sharer.php was called with an unknown (to me at least) app-id as parameter. After creating a facebook app for the website in question and putting the newly created app-id as parameter ..

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

.. it worked.

For debugguing purposes it could be helpful to put another source for js.src:

```
[...]
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk/debug.js[...]
[...]
```

This will log debugging messages to the js-console. (As can be read up here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0#advancedsetup)